# Select/Where com parâmetro não funciona no Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, select, where

Estou efetuando um select com where via PHP e Oracle, quando recebe pelo parâmetro ocorre um erro:

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\includes\Read.php on line 52
>   Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\index.php on line

Se eu passar o parâmetro direto funciona normalmente, conforme linha comentada, funciona.

```
public function readAnexos($CDLICITACAO) {

    try{
        //$id = '012103';
        $id = $CDLICITACAO;

            $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM TBLICITCAO WHERE CDLICITACAO = $id";
            $stid = oci_parse($this->db, $sql_query);

            oci_execute($stid);
            return $stid;

        }

    catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage() . "<br>Error na linha:  ";
        echo "<b>" . $e->getTraceAsString()."</b>";
        parent::fechar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na identificação do `$id`, não está passando a variável e sim a `string '$id'` para ser comparada com um campo provavelmente inteiro.

Para resolver seu problema substitua a linha da query por:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM TBLICITCAO WHERE CDLICITACAO = ".$id;
```

Comment: string(80) "SELECT * FROM TBLICITCAO WHERE CDLICITACAO = 014384" 
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\includes\Read.php on line 48

Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\index.php on line 72

Comment: Qual o código das linhas 48 e 72?

Comment: Read.php
oci_execute($stid);

index.php
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid)) {
    $dataAnexos[] = array("IDANEXO" => $row['IDANEXO'],
                    "CDLICITACAO"   => $row['CDLICITACAO'],
                    "NARQUIVO"      => $row['NARQUIVO'],
                    "DIRARQUIVO"    => $row['DIRARQUIVO']);
}

Comment: @AndreC O nome da tabela (TBLICITACAO) e o nome do campo (CDLICITACAO) estão em maiusculo no bd? Se estiverem minusculo, tente passar pra minusculo no php e veja se algo muda.

Comment: Estão todos maiúsculo... o engraçado é que só eu mudar o $id = 013203 funciona... se eu deixo o parâmetro não...
porém o parâmetro está chegando corretamente tb.

a coluna no banco é VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)

Answer (score 0):

Mesmo assim não funcionou, gerou um erro... porém o sql está correto, se eu executar ele no banco de dados, funciona.

> string(80) "SELECT * FROM TBLICITCAO WHERE CDLICITACAO = 014384"

Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\includes\Read.php on line 48

Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\index.php on line 72

Comment: CDLICITACAO = '014384" "